# Dynamically added FloatingActionButton does not adopt behavior to move with the Snackbar

Tags: android, material-design, android-snackbar, floating-action-button

I'm trying to add a `FloatingActionButton` to a `CoordinatorLayout` in my `Activity`'s `onCreate()`. This is basically working. It receives `Coordinator.LayoutParams` with `gravity = BOTTOM | RIGHT`. When the `Snackbar` (attached to the same coordinator) pops in, it underlays the button though.

If I embed the `FloatingActionButton` into the coordinator via xml it works as advertised.

The embedded button and the dynamically added one are based on the same xml source, added via `<include />` (working) and via `addView( inflate( ... ) )` (not working). The view hierarchy in the debugging tool is identical.

One strange thing I noticed here, is that in `onCreate()`, after inflating/adding, the behavior of the fab is `null`. Before the `Snackbar` appears, it magically received a `FloatingActionButton.Behavior`.

Manually setting the `FloatingActionButton.Behavior` while adding the view did not help.

It would help me a lot to understand what is going on, if I could access the source code of the design library, but it seems to be not available yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By now inflating a `FloatingActionButton` in code, when there is a `Snackbar` in the same `CoordinatorLayout`, should work just fine.